# Grails 2.x -Including Javascript/Jquery Libraries in all GSP files

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have worked in Grails 1.3.7 there i use to include all my javascript and jquery library in main.gsp, so that those libraries will automatically gets included in all other GSP pages. but Grails 2.x version does not behave like that.

so in grails 2.0+ ,where to include my javascript/jquery Libraries so that its automatically includes in all GSP pages?

Comment: Grails 2 uses the [resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) for linking static resources. It's also possible to include resources in you (main) layout. From the [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/4.%20Using%20resources.html#4.1%20Linking%20to%20CSS,%20JavaScript%20etc.): _You can of course include any common modules you require in your sitemesh layout using <r:require> but they must appear before the first <r:layoutResources/>._

Answer (score 0):

just include it in your `main.gsp` file under the `views/layouts` directory (or any other layout file you've placed there an plan on using for styling, etc. your site). every page which includes this layout will automatically have the libraries, stylesheets, etc. included when you call 'em...

main.gsp (default):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'mobile.css')}" type="text/css">
    <g:layoutHead/>
    <r:layoutResources />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grailsLogo" role="banner"><a href="http://grails.org"><img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'grails_logo.png')}" alt="Grails"/></a></div>
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
    <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
    <g:javascript library="application"/>
    <r:layoutResources />
</body>
```